# Oracle SQL Anniversary Dates Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need some assistance in creating a query which shows the anniversary of employees in the business. I need the report to run and show results within two dates I select. I would like the report to show historical anniversary data too.

I would like columns NAME, ANNIVERSARY DATE, YEARS WITH BUSINESS

Columns I have in the dataset is name and date of employment.

Any help is appreciated!

TIA

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where you stoped? What doesn't work?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` and `ADD_MONTHS`:

```sql
SELECT name,
       date_of_employment,
       ADD_MONTHS(
         date_of_employment,
         (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_of_employment))*12
       ) AS anniversary,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, date_of_employment)/12
         AS years_with_business,
       TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, date_of_employment)/12)
         AS full_years_with_business
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name, date_of_employment ) AS
SELECT 'Alice',   ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), -120) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl',   ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 0), -120) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol',   ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1), -120) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra',   ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1),  +12) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emma',    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 0),  +12) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Frances', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1),  +12) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT | ANNIVERSARY | YEARS_WITH_BUSINESS | FULL_YEARS_WITH_BUSINESS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Alice | 2011-08-18 00:00:00 | 2021-08-18 00:00:00 | 10.00435082511947431302270011947431302267 | 10 |
> | Beryl | 2011-08-19 00:00:00 | 2021-08-19 00:00:00 | 10 | 10 |
> | Carol | 2011-08-20 00:00:00 | 2021-08-20 00:00:00 | 9.99897448103345280764635603345280764633 | 9 |
> | Debra | 2022-08-18 00:00:00 | 2021-08-18 00:00:00 | -.9956491748805256869772998805256869773 | 0 |
> | Emma | 2022-08-19 00:00:00 | 2021-08-19 00:00:00 | -1 | -1 |
> | Frances | 2022-08-20 00:00:00 | 2021-08-20 00:00:00 | -1.00102551896654719235364396654719235364 | -1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5f49333500339dac64b94ebe86051fa)*

Comment: Thank you! If i want to add a date parameter where i can choose two dates, do i need to adjust the (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_of_employment))*12
       ) AS anniversary query and instead of SYSDATE i add &TO_DATE ?

Comment: Just replace `SYSDATE` and `date_of_employment` with your two other dates.

Comment: If I was to run a period from 01/04/2020 - 31/03/2021, this brings back only anniversaries in year 2021 and not all the anniversaries in between the two dates? can you advise what i will need to amend to show the correct results? TIA

Comment: @Yasir You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68848855/edit) your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your table; the `INSERT` statements for a minimal example of your data; the expected output for that sample data; and an explanation of why you want that expected output. You haven't got the results you expect because you have not told us what you expect and we are not telepathic so we just gave our best interpretation of the question.